# How to set 'y > 0' formula in set_xlim of matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to set x range according to y value in plotting graph such as y > 0 but I'm not sure how to set this one. Could you let me know how to set it?

```
df = pd.read_csv(file.csv)
x = np.array(df1['A'])
y = np.array(df1['B'])
z = np.array(df1['C'])

x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y < 0) | (y > 100), x)

fig, (ax2, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=2)

# range of ax1.set_xlim and ax1.set_xlim is same. 
ax1.set_ylim([-10, 40])
ax2.set_ylim([-5, 5])
ax1.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])
ax2.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])
```

Comment: is it a fixed transformation from `y_lim` to `x_lim`?

Comment: @learner I want to set the '''xlim''' and '''ylim''' be automatic from data but I'm not sure how to set these values. I just get these values from data frame of CSV file.

Comment: you can do `np.min` for finding the minimum of the data and set it to lower bound of `x_lim`. Repeat similarly for upper bound. Check my answer below for implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the x-limits to the range of the y-axis, you can use a masked array and get its minimum and maximum.

In the example below, at the left both subplots get the x-limits where either y or z are in range. At the right, each subplot only gets the x-range where its corresponding y is in range.

For demonstration purposes, the example creates a data frame from some dummy data.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.linspace(-1, 4, 500)
b = np.sin(a) * 100
c = np.cos(a) * 150
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c})
x = np.array(df['A'])
y = np.array(df['B'])
z = np.array(df['C'])

fig, ((ax1, ax3),(ax2, ax4)) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2)

ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax3.set_xlabel('x')
ax4.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax3.set_ylabel('y')
ax2.set_ylabel('z')
ax4.set_ylabel('z')

ymin = 1
ymax = 100
zmin = 1
zmax = 150
x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where(((y < ymin) | (y > ymax)) & ((z < zmin) | (z > zmax)), x)
x_for_ax3 = np.ma.masked_where((y < ymin) | (y > ymax), x)
x_for_ax4 = np.ma.masked_where((z < zmin) | (z > zmax), x)

ax1.plot(x, y)
ax3.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])
ax3.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])

ax2.plot(x, z)
ax4.plot(x, z)
ax2.set_ylim([zmin, zmax])
ax4.set_ylim([zmin, zmax])

ax1.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])
ax2.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])
ax1.set_title('x limited to y and z range')
ax2.set_title('x limited to y and z range')

ax3.set_xlim([x_for_ax3.min(), x_for_ax3.max()])
ax3.set_title('x limited to y range')

ax4.set_xlim([x_for_ax4.min(), x_for_ax4.max()])
ax4.set_title('x limited to z range')

plt.tight_layout(w_pad=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand your example because it was created using pandas to get the CSV data frame and then plotting graph.

Comment: Whether the data comes from a pandas dataframe or directly from numpy arrays, doesn't make much difference. I now include the creation of a dummy pandas dataframe to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: I want to plot the scope of the red box as above. And there is no plotting line when I have added the code as below. 
`y_min = 0
y_max = 100
x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y > y_min) | (z < y_max), x)
ax1.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), x_for_ax1.max()])`

Comment: You seem to be mixing y and z.  Also, the masking means invisible where masked, so `<` and `>` need to be reversed. You could use `x_for_ax1 = np.ma.masked_where((y < y_min) | (y > y_max)`.    For setting the right limit, you need to find a good way to describe mathematically what you want.  Otherwise, you could just use some fixed value, like `ax1.set_xlim([x_for_ax1.min(), 128]`

Comment: I've set the '(y < 0) | (y > 100)' so that the value less than 0 to be invisible but the changed thing was just filling the lineless part as above. I can't find where is the problem.

Comment: Better use '(y <= 0) | (y > 100)', because y is exactly zero at the unwanted part. Or even use  '(y < 0.001)' to take possible approximation errors into account